# How can I center the table in the page?

Tags: css

I Have this css:

```
.tableheader {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.text1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
......
<table class = bordergray cellspacing=1 cellpadding=5>
<tr class = tableheader  valign="bottom">
<caption>Shining Star Award</caption>
<td>Month</td>
<td>employee first name</td>
<td>employee last name</td>
<td>stars<br/></td>
</tr>

<cfoutput query="shiningStar">
<tr class = text1>
<td>#</td>
<td>#</td>
<td>#</td>
<td>#</td>
</tr>
</cfoutput>
</table>
```

I would like the table to appear in the center of the page , or aleast not in the left corner?
How would I do that?

Comment: See [Centering in the Unknown](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)

Comment: For starters, your HTML classes need to be in quotation marks. To center the table, just set a width for the table and then do `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: @orial thanks I may end up using something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`align="center"` in your `table` tag

[**Demo 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/C79yy/)

or

mention `margin: 0 auto;` in your css for `table` class

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/2LapB/)

Don't forget to put `""` double quotation around classes name

Answer (score 2):

using `margin: 0 auto`
sample:
 
`.bordergray{
   margin: 0 auto;
}`
http://jsfiddle.net/vDzx4/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C3zWM/2/)

You HTML markup is invalid -> `classes` should be quoted like `class="someclass"`

To center an element in the page you should give it `fixed width` and use `margin:0 auto`.

**HTML**

```
<table class="bordergray" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
<tr class="tableheader"  valign="bottom">
<caption>Shining Star Award</caption>
<td>Month</td>
<td>employee first name</td>
<td>employee last name</td>
<td>stars<br/></td>
</tr>

<cfoutput query="shiningStar">
<tr class="text1">
<td>#</td>
<td>#</td>
<td>#</td>
<td>#</td>
</tr>
</cfoutput>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.bordergray{
    width:300px; /*fixed width for aligning the element center*/
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:0 auto; /*centers the element*/


}
.tableheader {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
.text1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```